# How to make a Symfony 5.4 (PHP 7.4) project connect to a postgreSQL database using a specific schema

Tags: schema, postgresql-15, symfony5.4

I have been trying since a moment to make a Symfony (5.4) (PHP 7.4) project interact with a postgreSQL (15.5) database server.
It it a database that already exist with many schema an i just want to create table base on my Symfony entities in one of these schema.

When i execute "php bin/console make:migration" it get all informations about all the schemas in the database and the tables and sequences they contain while i just want the connection to focus on an unique schema (we will call this schema "thedesignedschema")

And when I try to execute all the migration as the "php bin/console make:migration" command provide them i get errors like :

SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE doctrine_migration_versions (version VARCHAR(19...

I search on the documentation how to tell symfony that it must just use "thedesignedschema".
I tried to add "schema: thedesignedschema" in doctrine.yaml, it isn't recognise.
I try to pass the schema in the URL, nothing.